# Blank page on trying to display webapi service data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to consume the webapi service that I built using angularjs. However, the page appears to be blank after running.

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module("productsApp", ["productService"]);

app.controller("productsController", function ($scope, product) {
    $scope.products = product.query();
});
```

**Service.js**

```
(function () {
    angular.module("productService", ["ngResource"]).
    factory("product", function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:55755/api/products/:id');
    });
}());
```

**Html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="productsApp">
    <div ng-controller="productsController as vm">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="p in vm.products">
                    <td>{{ p.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.productCode }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.releaseDate | date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.price | currency }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put here a demo?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `controllerAs` syntax in view but not in controller

Try changing to:

```
app.controller("productsController", function ( product) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.products = product.query();
});
```

When using `controllerAs` you only need `$scope` for things like angular events and `$watch`